# Modify List Header Utilizing XSL

Tags: xslt

I am working with SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint Designer 2010 (and I'm a newbie to SharePoint) striving to modify a list header. Since this is a corporate site there are a lot of limitations, so basically I believe I can only use XSL to do the header modifications needed. Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031524/how-to-configure-multicolumn-header-in-sharepoint-list Vadim Gremyachev posted a solution. But he is obviously a SharePoint pro and doesn't find necessary to explain things which are obvious to him. To me, unfortunately they are not.
I need step by step instructions of how to create a customized header of 3 rows and multiple columns for existing list.
Vadim, if you are reading this, I would greatly appreciate your help!

Thanks,
Svet

Comment: Can you please provide the list and the format of the header you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Svet,

as was pointed in the original answer, there are two options how to customize List View via XSLT:

- Inline editing of xsl using SharePoint Designer as described in article [Create a custom list view using SharePoint Designer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-custom-list-view-using-sharepoint-designer-HA010379079.aspx?fromAR=3)
- create a custom xsl template for a List View and  apply it via XSL Link property of XLV web part (i usually prefer this method)
  way

Below is demonstrated a complete solution how to customize List View for a Contacts list by creating a custom xsl template.

Steps:

Let's say we need to customize the view of a Contacts list

1. Create a custom xsl template for a List View (see the complete code listing below)
2. Save(upload) it for convenience in the same location where List form pages
   reside as shown on figure below[image]
3. Open List view page in edit mode, select List View web part and go to edit web part properties, specify `XSL Link` property value: `ContactsView.xsl`  as shown on figure below [image]
4. Save web part changes

That's it.

Fig 1. Original default view for a Contacts view

[image]

Fig 2. Customized view for a contacts view after applying custom xsl template
[image]

Code listing for a custom xsl template of Contacts list view

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <xsl:include href="/_layouts/xsl/main.xsl"/>
  <xsl:include href="/_layouts/xsl/internal.xsl"/>
    <xsl:template match="View" mode="full">
    <!-- Custom Header starts here -->
    <tr valign="top" class="ms-viewheadertr" style="background-color:#c0c0c0; border: ">
       <th class="ms-vh-icon" scope="col" colspan="8">Contacts info</th>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" class="ms-viewheadertr" style="background-color:#c0c0c0;">
       <th class="ms-vh-icon" scope="col" colspan="2"></th>
       <th class="ms-vh-icon" scope="col" colspan="2">Name</th>
       <th class="ms-vh-icon" scope="col" colspan="1"></th>
       <th class="ms-vh-icon" scope="col" colspan="2">Phone</th>
       <th class="ms-vh-icon" scope="col" colspan="1"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" class="ms-viewheadertr" style="background-color:#c0c0c0;">
       <th class="ms-vh-icon" scope="col" rowspan="2"><input type="checkbox" title="{$select_deselect_all}" onclick="ToggleAllItems(event,this,{$ViewCounter})" onfocus="EnsureSelectionHandlerOnFocus(event,this,{$ViewCounter})" /></th>
       <xsl:call-template name="FieldRef_Attachments_header"></xsl:call-template> <!-- Render attachments header -->
       <th class="ms-vh-icon" nowrap="nowrap" scope="col" onmouseover="OnChildColumn(this)">
         Last Name
       </th>
       <th class="ms-vh-icon" nowrap="nowrap" scope="col" onmouseover="OnChildColumn(this)">
         First Name
       </th>
       <th class="ms-vh-icon" nowrap="nowrap" scope="col" onmouseover="OnChildColumn(this)">
         Company
       </th>
       <th class="ms-vh-icon" nowrap="nowrap" scope="col" onmouseover="OnChildColumn(this)">
         Business Phone
       </th>
       <th class="ms-vh-icon" nowrap="nowrap" scope="col" onmouseover="OnChildColumn(this)">
         Home Phone
       </th>
       <th class="ms-vh-icon" nowrap="nowrap" scope="col" onmouseover="OnChildColumn(this)">
         E-mail Address
       </th>
    </tr>
    <!-- Custom Header ends here -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="RenderView" />  <!-- Render default view items -->
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="footer" select="." /> <!-- Render default view footer -->
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you Vadim. Your code works like a charm. My problem was that I missed to replace the ID used to refer the view in your original posting with the ID of my view.

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Svet, good to know! Glad this helped you :)