# How to change list column title using xsl in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, list-view, xslt, custom-field-types

I'm creating custom field type - lets name it 'MyCustomType'. I need to change its column title in List View. I tried to use xslt-transform in my fldtypes_MyCustomType.xsl with no luck - nothing changes.

I tried the following code:

```
<xsl:template name="FieldRef_MyCustomType_header" ddwrt:dvt_mode="header" 
              match="FieldRef[@Type='MyCustomType']" mode="header" priority="9">
  <th class="ms-vh-icon" nowrap="nowrap" scope="col" onmouseover="OnChildColumn(this)">
  <xsl:call-template name="dvt_headerfield">
     <xsl:with-param name="fieldname">MyCustomType</xsl:with-param>
     <xsl:with-param name="fieldtitle">This value I want to change</xsl:with-param>
     <xsl:with-param name="displayname">MyCustomType</xsl:with-param>
     <xsl:with-param name="fieldtype">MyCustomType</xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
  </th>
</xsl:template>
```

I copied this code from Sharepoint fldtypes.xsl, 'FieldRef_Attachments_header' template.

Please help me to make it works.

Comment: have a look into this example: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109277/modify-list-header-utilizing-xsl

Comment: This example is cool, but it manipulates with List View of entire List. I need to modify only my filed title, because my field can be added to any list via code or UI. So I can't predict what kind of list will use my field, and what columns there will be.

Answer (score 1):

I'd almost forget about this problem, but accidently I'd found the way to solve it.

The main difference between SP2013 and SP2010 - is javascript rendering! In 2013 - javascript is everywhere, and XsltListViewWebParts (classic list view) by default are rendering on client too. That's why **Xslt-transformations for header working, but not visible!** To see it, go to the List View Page -> "Change Page" -> "Change XsltListViewWebPart properties" -> find checkBox "Render on server" -> Save. XsltListViewWebPart will render at 2010-style and **you will see your header from Xslt**.

But how to do my custom header **in 2013-style, with client render**? The answer is - Javascript. **You'll have to override javascript header rendering**. You can find it in clienttemplates.js

So, full solution is:

1. When you creating your custom field type, you have to override JS-link for your field:

   ```
   public class MyCustomType: SPFieldLookup
   {        
      private const string JSLinkUrl = "~site/_layouts /15/MyCustomType/MyCustomType.js";

      public override string JSLink
      {
          get { return JSLinkUrl; }
          set { base.JSLink = value; }
      }

     //constructors and other logic
   }
   ```

   In file `/_layouts /15/MyCustomType/MyCustomType.js` you will make all javascript transformations for your field.
2. Create `MyCustomType/MyCustomType.js` in the `LAYOUTS` folder. And there, override `renderHeader` field of `spMgr` object:

   ```
   (function () {
      spMgr.RenderHeader = function (renderCtx, field) {
           //...
           //you'll have to copy all SPMgr functions from clientTemplates.js 
           //if you want render other fields headers propertly.
           //Simply find string 'function SPMgr() {' and grab this function fully
           //then add you header rendering
           //...
           if (field.Name == 'SelectedFlag')
               return RenderSelectedFlagHeader(renderCtx, field);
           else if (field.Name == 'Checkmark')
               return RenderCheckmarkHeader(renderCtx, field);
           var fieldHeaderRenderMap = {
               Attachments: RenderAttachmentsHeader,
               Computed: RenderComputedHeader,
               CrossProjectLink: RenderCrossProjectLinkHeader,
               Recurrence: RenderRecurrenceHeader,
               DateTime: RenderDateTimeHeader
           };
           var headerRenderer = fieldHeaderRenderMap[field.Type];

           if (field.FieldType == 'MyCustomType')
               return RenderMyCustomHeader(renderCtx, field); //this is our rendering!
           else {
               if (headerRenderer != null)
                   return headerRenderer(renderCtx, field);
               return RenderDefaultHeader(renderCtx, field);
           }        
       }
   })(); 
   function RenderMyCustomHeader(renderCtx, field) {
       var iStr = '<th scope="col" onmouseover="OnChildColumn(this)" style="max-width: 500px;" class="ms-vh2" onmousedown="ListHeaderMenu_OnMouseDown(this);">';   
       iStr += "My field -my header from js";
       iStr += '</th>';
       return iStr;
   }
   ```

**Unfortunately, I hadn't find the solution without full overriding `SPMgr` function from `clienttemplates.js`. If someone will find it - please add it here!**

**Update:**

And here is the correct XSLT-rendering (`fldtypes_MyCustomType.xsl`) for Server-side rendering in SP2010-style:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" >
      <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>

      <xsl:template name="FieldRef_MyCustomType_header" 
                    match="FieldRef[@FieldType='MyCustomType']" 
                    ddwrt:dvt_mode="header" mode="header" priority="9">
        <th class="ms-vh-icon" nowrap="nowrap" scope="col" onmouseover="OnChildColumn(this)">
          <xsl:attribute name="class">ms-vh2</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:call-template name="dvt_headerfield">
            <xsl:with-param name="fieldname"><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="fieldtitle">
              MyCustomType from XSL 
            </xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="displayname"><xsl:value-of select="@DisplayName"/></xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="fieldtype">x:string</xsl:with-param>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </th>
      </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <xsl:call-template name="dvt_headerfield">
> ```

I think you have a typo, it should be `dvt.headerfield`. Although I did see posts using the underscore, [more authoritative posts like this one](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2010/09/14/sharepoint-extending-the-dvwp-_e2_80_93-part-35-putting-it-all-together-or-aspx/) uses the dot.

You also write "nothing happens", are you positive that the template `FieldRef_MyCustomType_header` is ever called? you can check this by adding something like:

```
<xsl:comment>Hey, I hit my template!</xsl:comment>
```

at the top of the template, and then check the output.

Comment: Not, it's not a typo. First, I've copied this piece of code from `15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\XSL\fldtypes.xsl`, from template `FieldRef_Attachments_header`. Second, If I use `dvt.headerfield` - I get an error 'could not load webpart' in list view. Also, my template is never called.

Comment: @OlgaGolubeva, so you have the choice between template never called, and template name raising an error. You should search for what calls `FieldRef_MyCustomType_header` (if that is indeed currently not called), and analyze your way back step by step.